# How do I use Dataflow to calculate the top unique value results per key?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I'm relatively new to Dataflow and its programming model and struggling with a problem that requires calculating the top 10 weeks a customer has their highest spend. I apologise if this seems a silly question.

The data I have consists of customer IDs which I use as the key and a few million records containing a timestamp and a spend value.

I've created an Extract method that looks something like this (excluding logging and the date formatter). It receives a BigQuery table row from which I extract the customer ID, spend and timestamp from which I get the week number:

```
static class ExtractSpend extends DoFn<TableRow, KV<String, SpendByWeek>> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 0;

    @Override
    public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
        String custId = (String) row.get("customerID");
        LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.parse((String) row.get("timestamp"), dateTimeFormatter);

        WeekFields weekFields = WeekFields.of(Locale.getDefault());
        int weekNumber = date.get(weekFields.weekOfWeekBasedYear());

        Double spend = (Double) row.get("spend");

        SpendByWeek spendByWeek = new SpendByWeek(weekNumber, spend.doubleValue());
        c.output(KV.of(custId, spendByWeek));

   }
}
```

But I can't figure out how to take this output and group it in such a way that I can add the spend values per customer ID and week, sort them and output a `PCollection<String, List<Double>>` of each customer and their top 10 weekly spend values.

Would anyone be able to help me out with this, please?

Comment: Hi Darren, have you looked into the Sum and Top transforms in https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/library-transforms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to accomplish this using only grouping, you'd need to first group by customer ID and week to compute the `Sum` then move the week into the value and regroup by just the customer ID for computing the `Top`. You can also do this using windowing rather than putting the week in the key. See the end for some details on doing that.

Once you've done that, you have a `PCollection<KV<String, SpendByWeek>>` where each week occurs once for a given key.  You can determine the top `SpendByWeek` for each given user-id by defining a `Comparator<SpendByWeek>` that implements `Serializable` and using that with `Top.perKey()`.

---

Computing the Spend-Per-Week-Per-User with Windows

As mentioned at the top you can use windowing to help with computing the spend-per-week.

1. Write a DoFn similar to your ExtractSpend which takes a TableRow and outputs a KV which is individual rows of spend keyed by customer ID and output outputs using `outputWithTimestamp`.
2. Then apply a windowing transformation, such as `FixedWindows` which will take the divide the events into windows of the specified size. In your case, you likely want `FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardWeeks(1))` or `CalendarWindows.weeks(...)`.
3. Then apply a transform such as `Sum.doublesPerKey()`.

At this point, you'll have a `PCollection` which contains a per-week-window `KV<String, Double>` where each entry is the total spend for that key in the week.

4. Then you can run a `DoFn` that takes the hourly windows and moves that information into the value (so now you have `KV<String, SpendAndWeek>`)
5. Apply a Window.into to switch to `GlobalWindows`
6. And then apply the `Top.perKey` operation as described above.